# Bug in patch() in R2016a?

Tags: matlab, plot

When I execute the following command on MATLAB **R2016a**:

```
patch([0 1 1 0],....
      [0 0 1 1],...
      cat(3, [0.55 0.45 0 0],...
             [0.45 0.35 0 0],...
             [0.25 0.15 0 0]),...
      'facecolor', 'interp');
```

I get:

> Error using patch
>
> Vectors must be the same length.

However, I can execute it perfectly fine in *any* other version. I tried on **R2010a**, **R2014a** and **R2017a**, all with the same result:

[image]

The (relevant) documentation (`help patch`) states:

> patch(X,Y,C) creates one or more filled polygons [...] If C is 1-by-n-by-3, where n is the number of columns of X and Y, then each face j is flat colored by the RGB triplet C(1,j,:).

So clearly, this is a bug in R2016a. But I can't find a bug report about this...Can anyone point me in the right direction?

And what would be the best workaround to achieve the desired effect, *version agnostically*?

Comment: Does `patch([0 1 1 0],[0 0 1 1],cat(3, [0.55 0.45 0 0].',[0.45 0.35 0 0].',[0.25 0.15 0 0].'),'facecolor', 'interp');` work for you? (notice the transpose operation)

Comment: @Lior well, it does on R2017a. I don't have access to R2016a right now, I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: @Lior Yes, that seems to work...strange! If you turn that into an answer, I can at least give you some credit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RGB triplets should be transposed:

```
patch([0 1 1 0], [0 0 1 1],...
      cat(3, [0.55 0.45 0 0].',...
             [0.45 0.35 0 0].',...  % <- NOTE: transposed
             [0.25 0.15 0 0].'),...
      'facecolor', 'interp');
```

Comment: Thanks :) It's still a bug though, since it disagrees with what is described in the help on `patch()`...But it seems to work on all versions I've tried.

Comment: In fact, the "proper" way to do this is to also transpose `X` and `Y`, since in the case that `X` and `Y` are matrices, each column corresponds to vertex.

Comment: But it's true that the documentation of this function (at least in my version of Matlab) doesn't mention explicitly or clearly enough the required form of the color matrix (as far as I can tell).

Comment: I typed `help patch`, which is where the quote comes from. Perhaps `doc patch` says something different? Let's check

Comment: Also, it behaves differently on versions both before and after R2016a...so there's definitely something "unique" about it in R2016a :)

Comment: Yes, in `doc patch` there's hardly any mention on the required size of `C` in this context...oh well, thanks for this finding.

Comment: @Rody It's annoying how Mathworks sometimes include less information in `doc` / web than in `help`.